# Limit of the sequence $\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{(n+1)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

To find the limit of the sequence $$\left\{ \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{(n+1)}}\right\}$$

It is clear that for $n>3,$

$ (n+1)^n<n^{(n+1)}$

This $\implies 0<\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{(n+1)}}<1$ for $n>3$

Thus the sequence is bounded and also monotonic which implies this sequence is convergent.

But what is the limit of the sequence and how to find it?

Comment: Write it as $(1+1/n)^n\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @NDB got it!! Thanks a lot. It's 0 then :)

Comment: Once you have your solution, feel free to answer your own question here. The information can be helpful to other users!

Answer (score 2):

Note that:
$$\require{cancel}\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}=\frac{\color{#9999FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{n^n}}}}{\color{#9999FF}{\cancel{\color{black}{n^n}}}\!\!\!\!\cdot\!n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\!=\frac1n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\!\!\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\!\cdot\!e=0\;.$$
Hence you have:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}}=0\;.$$

Comment: Good answer! I have upvoted you.

Comment: @Angelo Thank you (also for the edit)!

Comment: You are welcome!